# how to match gre key using?

Tags: iptables, netfilter

I want to match on the gre tunnel key (5) using iptables, my command is
below:

```
iptables -A OUTPUT -t raw -p gre -o eth2 -m conntrack --ctrepldstport 5 -j LOG --log-level debug
```

However, this is not working.  Could anyone help point out where is wrong?

root@promg-2n-a-dhcp85:~/openvswitch# iptables --version
iptables v1.4.12

Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://www.gossamer-threads.com/lists/iptables/devel/66339

> While porting some changes of the 2.6.21-rc7 pptp/proto_gre conntrack
>   and nat modules to a 2.4.32 kernel I noticed that the gre_key function
>   returns a wrong pointer to the GRE key of a version 0 packet thus corrupting
>   the packet payload.
>   The intended behaviour for GREv0 packets is to act like
>   nf_conntrack_proto_generic/nf_nat_proto_unknown so I have ripped the
>   offending functions (not used anymore) and modified the xx_nat_proto_gre
>   modules to not touch version 0 (non PPTP) packets."

so nice way of fixing problems :-(

seems this patch was accepted silently, and matching by gre keys will newer work again in linux, contrary to what proclaimed in iptables man.

Answer (score 0):

Shameless self advertising of one of my OSS modules. A while ago I wrote a custom IPTables module "xt_bfl4" to solve a IPv6 matching problem, it also works in this case.

Use the BPF expression below to match for a key of 0x917e805a

```
udp[0:1]&0x20=0x20 and ((udp[0:1]&0xA0=0x20 and udp[4:4]=0x917e805a) or (udp[0:1]&0xA0=0xA0 and udp[16:4]=0x917e805a))
```

This compiles to:

```
(000) ldb      [0]
(001) and      #0x20
(002) jeq      #0x20            jt 3    jf 12
(003) ldb      [0]
(004) and      #0xa0
(005) jeq      #0x20            jt 6    jf 8
(006) ld       [4]
(007) jeq      #0x917e805a      jt 11   jf 12
(008) jeq      #0xa0            jt 9    jf 12
(009) ld       [16]
(010) jeq      #0x917e805a      jt 11   jf 12
(011) ret      #65535
(012) ret      #0
```

or in the format required by xt_bpf & xt_bpfl4:

```
13,48 0 0 0,84 0 0 32,21 0 9 32,48 0 0 0,84 0 0 160,21 0 2 32,32 0 0 4,21 3 4 2440986714,21 0 3 160,32 0 0 16,21 0 1 2440986714,6 0 0 65535,6 0 0 0
```

And so match with the following rule:

```
iptables -I INPUT -p 47 -m bpfl4 --bytecodel4 '13,48 0 0 0,84 0 0 32,21 0 9 32,48 0 0 0,84 0 0 160,21 0 2 32,32 0 0 4,21 3 4 2440986714,21 0 3 160,32 0 0 16,21 0 1 2440986714,6 0 0 65535,6 0 0 0'
```